# QTableView, select and shift+click

Tags: c++, qt, model-view-controller

I have a small but quite annoying problem with Qt's QTableView

Since my view is used in a StackedLayout, I have to select a line based on a field in an other page (that part works ok).

So when I display this view, I select the line I want with a simple

```
QItemSelection selection = line2selection(line);
d_view->selectionModel()->select(selection, QItemSelectionModel::Select);
```

where line2selection creates a QItemSelection filled with all the indexes for the whole line.

As I sais, this part works ok, but introduce another problem:

When I do a shift+click to select several lines at once (which works great if I don't select a line "programatically"), it always stars the selection from the first line instead of the starting from the line currently selected.

Any idea how I could fix the problem?

btw, I tried to call the selectRow method on my view too, but doesn't seem to be much better...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the `QItemSelectionModel::Current` flag to `QItemSelectionModel::Select` so the ["current" item index](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qitemselectionmodel.html#setCurrentIndex) is updated, this index acts as the anchor for the shift+click multi-selects

Comment: for some reason, adding this flag didn't help, but calling setCurrentIndex with the first index of my selection did the trick, not really sure why...
Even with the Current flag added, currentIndex always returned an invalid index...